# :after content fallback if font doesn't exist

Tags: html, css, fonts

Is there a way to have a fallback if a font doesn't exist?

I have an Icon Font, that uses `content: '\E5CC';` However if the font doesn't exist, can I fallback to `content: '/';`?

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons');

a:after {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    content: '\E5CC'; 
    // Fallback
    content: '/';
}
```

In this CSS library, I would like to be able to fallback if Material Icons isn't used or a different icon framework is used.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article about it: 
https://www.zachleat.com/web/comprehensive-webfonts/

Basically, you'd need some javascript to check if the font is loaded.
Here's one example for the js: https://github.com/bramstein/fontfaceobserver

You would create the default style you want, for example, a simple disc.  After the font is loaded, you would then apply a class, for example 'ok' to all of your icons.

CSS would look something like this:

```
.icon:after {
    content:"";
    display:block; 
    width:10px; 
    height:10px; 
    border-radius:50%; 
    background-color:#ccc;
}

.icon.ok:after {
    content: '\E5CC'; 
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
}
```